# postgresql RDS - could not write to hash-join temporary file: No space left on device

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I am having an issue with RDS(postgresql).

`could not write to hash-join temporary file: No space left on device`

Any idea of how this can be fixed?

Note: The storage is enough, so I don't think this is the issue

Comment: How do you know the storage is enough?  Can you share the full query with us, and describe how the tables are created (i.e., how many columns, how many rows, etc.)?